# Given aspect ratio of a rectangle, find maximum scale and angle to fit it inside another rectangle

Tags: algorithm, rotation, geometry, pseudocode

I've read a few dozen questions on this topic, but none seem to be exactly what I'm looking for, so I'm hoping this isn't a duplicate.

I have an image, whose **aspect ratio I want to maintain,** because it's an image.

I want to find the **largest scale** factor, and **corresponding angle** between 0 and 90 degrees inclusive, such that the image will fit wholly inside a given rectangle.

**Example 1**:  If the image and rectangle are the same ratio, the angle will be 0, and the scale factor will be the ratio of the rectangle's width to the image's width.  (Or height-to-height.)

**Example 2**:  If the image and rectangle ratios are the inverse of each other, the scale factor will be the same as the first example, but the angle will be 90 degrees.

So, for the general case, given image.width, image.height, rect.width, rect.height, how do I find image.scale and image.angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out on my own.

First, calculate the aspect ratio.  If your image is 1:1, there's no point in this, because the angle is always zero, and the scale is always min(Width, Height).  Degeneration.

Otherwise, you can use this:

```
// assuming below that Width and Height are the rectangle's

_imageAspect = _image.width / _image.height;
if (_imageAspect == 1) { // div by zero implied
    trace( "square image...this does not lend itself to rotation ;)" );
    return;
}
_imageAspectSq = Math.pow( _imageAspect, 2 );

var rotate:Float;
var newHeight:Float;
if (Width > Height && Width / Height > _imageAspect) { // wider aspect than the image
    newHeight = Height;
    rotate = 0;
} else if (Height > Width && Height / Width > _imageAspect) { // skinnier aspect than the image rotated 90 degrees
    newHeight = Width;
    rotate = Math.PI / 2;
} else {
    var hPrime = (_imageAspect * Width - _imageAspectSq * Height) / ( 1 - _imageAspectSq );
    var wPrime = _imageAspect * (Height - hPrime);
    rotate = Math.atan2( hPrime, wPrime );
    var sine = Math.sin(rotate);
    if (sine == 0) {
        newHeight = Height;
    } else {
        newHeight = (Width - wPrime) / sine;
    }
}
```

The first two cases are also degenerate: the image's aspect ratio is less than the rectangle.  This is similar to the square-within-a-rectangle case, except that in that case, the square is *always* degenerate.

The code assumes radians instead of degrees, but it's not hard to convert.

(Also I'm a bit shocked that my browser's dictionary didn't have 'radians'.)